# Program gets stuck after assigning boolean value from class

Tags: java, class

I have a program that assigns a boolean value from a class that implements a  (the boolean type). But when I run the program it gets stuck after I assign the boolean value from the class.

Here is my code:

The class:

```
public static class TCP_Ping implements Callable<Boolean> {

        private final BufferedReader in;
        private final PrintWriter out;
        private final String ip;
        private final int port;
        private final int time;

        public TCP_Ping(BufferedReader _in, PrintWriter _out, String _ip,
                int _port, int _time) {

            this.in = _in;
            this.out = _out;
            this.ip = _ip;
            this.port = _port;
            this.time = _time;

        }

        @Override
        public Boolean call() {

            boolean returnValue = false;
            String address = ip + ":" + port;
            long before = System.nanoTime();
            out.println(new byte[64]);
            System.out.println("(" + time + ") Sent 64 bytes of data to "
                    + address + "...");

            try {

                if ((in.readLine()) != null) {

                    int size = in.readLine().toString().getBytes().length;
                    long after = System.nanoTime();
                    long s = ((after - before) / 1000000L) / 1000;
                    System.out.println("(" + time + ") Recieved reply from "
                            + address + " (" + size + " bytes), time = " + s
                            + " seconds...");
                    returnValue = true;

                } else if ((in.readLine()) == null) {

                    long after = System.nanoTime();
                    long s = ((after - before) / 1000000L) / 1000;
                    System.out.println("(" + time
                            + ") Failed to recieve reply from " + address
                            + ", time = " + s + " seconds...");
                    returnValue = false;

                }

            } catch (IOException exc) {

                long after = System.nanoTime();
                long s = ((after - before) / 1000000L) / 1000;
                System.err.println("(" + time
                        + ") Failed to recieve reply from " + address
                        + ", time = " + s + " seconds...");
                returnValue = false;

            }

            return returnValue;

        }

    }
```

Where the boolean gets assigned:

```
System.out.println("Starting ping...");
            System.out.println("Will ping " + address
                    + " with 64 bytes of data...");

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final FutureTask<Boolean> ft1 = new FutureTask<Boolean>(
                    new TCP_Ping(in, out, ip, port, 1));
            Thread t1 = new Thread(ft1);
            t1.start();

            try {

                while (t1.isAlive()) {

                    t1.join(20000);

                    if (((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 20000)
                            && t1.isAlive()) {
                        t1.interrupt();
                        System.out
                                .println("(1) - Failed to receive reply from "
                                        + address
                                        + ", since the ping timed out, time = 20 seconds...");
                        result = false;
                        break;

                    }

                    break;

                }

            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {

                System.err
                        .println("(1) - An interuption occurred during a ping to "
                                + address + "...");

            }

            try {

                result = ft1.get();

            } catch (Exception exc) {

                System.err.println("Uh, oh! An internal error occurred!");

            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gets stuck"? You've posted a lot of code - could you try to cut it down to a shorter example which still demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Well, after it runs the part of the code where the boolean gets assigned, it will not do anything afterwords

Comment: See my answer. It's trying to read at least two lines from `in`. You haven't shown where `in` comes from, which doesn't help. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions about asking good questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but I suspect this is the problem:

```
if ((in.readLine()) != null) {
    int size = in.readLine().toString().getBytes().length;
```

That reads *two* lines from the input. You almost certainly didn't mean that. I suspect you wanted something like:

```
String line = in.readLine();
if (line != null) {
    int size = line.getBytes().length;
```

... although I'd *strongly* advise against using `String.getBytes` without specifying an encoding.

Likewise you're reading yet *another* line here:

```
} else if ((in.readLine()) == null) {
```

... although given that you'd only get into the `else` condition if you've read the final line, it's not clear why you've got a condition here at all. I think you just mean a plain `else` clause.